Selection of the type of resistors and capacitors
I’m currently working on an ArtNet Node project using a Teensy 4.1 and aiming to build a 3 Universe ArtNet Node with Ethernet connectivity.
Since I will be building the circuit on a breadboard I do not want to use SMD resistors and capacitors. What kind of resistors should I use (carbon film, metal film or thin film resistors) and what and what tolerances should I choose (or where can I find them in the data sheet)?
I have the same question about capacitors. For 100nF I would have simply used ceramic capacitors and electrolytic capacitors for the 2.2uF. Can I do that or should I use different capacitors and why?



Just stick to 1% resistors. Ceramic caps will have very low ESR so they can/should pretty much always be used when you have the option. The non-polarity is also a bonus when hand soldering. There's no reason why you'd need an electrolyte cap at just 2.2uF@5V.

That being said, breadboards are horrible for pretty much every purpose, including learning and prototyping. Picking up soldering early on is a good idea. The worst cold solder joint perfboard mess you can imagine will still be 10 times better than breadboard crap.

You might want to consider adding some protection to the RS485 busses. MAX485s aren’t particularly robust. Should be plenty of examples on the web.

The suggested 1% resistors are way too tight you need. They might cost more, but if they don't then go for it.
The resistor tolerace may or may not be important, and type of resistor between the types you mentioned may be irrelevant. As long as you don't choose a wirewound resistor.
The value may be more important than tolerance.
For example, the enable pull-up. The signal never toggles, and the chip has leakage current of 2 microamps. So it does not matter if the resistor is 4.7 kilo-ohms, or 1 megaohm, or no resistor so directly tied to 5V.
The CC resistors are mandated by USB specs and need to be within 20% of 5.1 kohms if you are not trying to detect amount of power available, or 10% if you want to detect amount of power available.
The 22 ohms are likely incorrect for this MCU. The MCU documentation says the USB pins connect directly to connector. Some older MCUs like AVRs used on Arduinos do not have USB compatible IO pins so they need external 22 ohm resistors. For ATMega8U, the documentation mandates 22R 5% resistors.
The 4k7 pull-up for optocoupler output may also be incorrect value. For example Vishay recommends max 4k. Many parameters are measured with 1k or 350 ohm resistors. 4k7 may be too high value and it may take too long for the signal to rise and it may distort the signal duty cycle. The resistor tolerance directly translates to tolerance in current and rise time.
The 240 ohm resistor for LED drive almost directly translates resistor tolerance to current. The current is likely not too small and not too large even with 10% tolerance. The LED forward voltage will vary more, which is why total tolerance of current based on LED forward voltage and 3.3V supply tolerance should be considered, as 10% could be too much. 5% resistors is usually used for MIDI which also uses optoisolators.
Capacitors of 100nF should be ceramic, maybe X7R. They usually come with 20% tolerance. That isn't the whole tolerance, as it will also vary according to temperature and voltage applied to capacitor. But for supply bypassing, generally any 100nF will do.
The 2.2uF is not worth being an electrolytic. The Recom module works at tens of kHz so it makes more sense to be ceramic for better high frequency use than electrolytic. But indeed electrolytics generally come with 20% tolerance.
Now, a few comment about the parts you did not ask.
The Recom module is badly regulated so it needs enough load to be at 5V, otherwise it may be +10% at 10% of the current and without load it goes higher to +25%. That is out of nominal operaring parameters for the 5V chips and may damage them.
The use of 74HC32 is weird. It tries to serve as a buffer. But it's powered from 5V, which does not make much sense, as a HC type chip may in worst case not work with 3.3V input signal, and at 3.3V supply, the MCU IO pins might just be about as strong if not stronger to drive the LEDs. The LEDs are still powered from 3.3V, even if the buffer will drive them with 5V and 0V. So the LEDs are 1.7V reverse biased when buffer outputs 5V. LEDs can handle 3V to 5V in reverse but generally it's not done.
